Interpretation of average marginal effect logistic regression model
I am currently writing a master thesis on the relationship between the unemployment rate (measured in percentage points) and first birth hazards (i.e. the probability of having a first child) using discrete-time hazard models.
I fitted a logistic regression model and calculated average marginal effects to interpret the coefficients. However, I am still not really sure about some interpretations of the average marginal effect.
As an example, I found an average marginal effect for the unemployment rate of -0.00153. Is the following interpretion correct?

a 1 percentage point increase in the unemployment rate is associated with a reduction in the probability of a first birth  by 0.153 percentage point.
A 10 percentage point increase in the unemployment rate is associated with a reduction in the proability of a first birth by 1.53 (=0.153*10) percentage points.

It is especially the second interpretation in terms of a 10 unit increase, that i'm unsure of and could not find any help on the internet. Any advice on interpretation is highly welcomed!
Thanks in advance :)

Technically, with a non-linear model like the logit, the interpretation of derivative-based AME is "the average change in probability of having a first child (on a [0,1] scale) associated with a tiny increase in $x$ from the current value." A one-unit increase is short-hand for tiny. If the function is really curvy, this distinction starts to matter.
If UR is on a [0, 100] scale, a one-unit increase is less severe (though still large economically in a world of low single-digit unemployment). In this case, your first interpretation is both correct and meaningful. It's a 0.00153 pp decline on a [0,1] scale and 0.153 pp on a [0, 100] scale. Some folks with a finance background might call that 15.3 basis points (or bips).
If UR is on a [0,1] scale, a one-unit increase is enormous. Here, the derivative-based approximation could be pretty different from the exact finite difference (a change in probabilities). It also entails considering meaningless covariate values since it will take everyone in your sample outside the [0,1] interval. What does a UR of 1.X even mean?
To sum up, if a 1 unit change in X is small, the derivative-based AME is equivalent to a finite difference. If it's a large change, then use a finite differences version of AME or rescale X so that the change becomes small.
There's one additional suggestion. UR is measured in percent, not percentage points. Changes in UE can be measured in percentage points or percent. So, UR going from 3% to 4% is a 1 pp change but a 33% change.

Thanks a lot for the elaborate explanation. UR is indeed measured on a [0, 100] scale. I was, however, still wondering whether the second interpretation also makes sense. If i'm for instance, interested in a a two-unit change, can I simply multiply the AME value by 2? Or do I have  to set it beforehand as the requested step size for calculation of the AME or rescale the variable beforehand so that a one-unit change corresponds to a 2 unit change?

The finite difference and rescaling will be more accurate, but going from 1 to 2 is not a big difference, so the approximation is usually not too bad.

Thanks a lot @dimitriy
